# HREF sends parameters to controller and returns a View

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller

So I am currently working on a project where I have a table that shows an overview of managers and the number of applications they are assigned to that currently have a certain status. What I am trying to do is when the user clicks on a number (which is the count) it returns a list view that queries from the database ONLY those applications that are assigned to that manager and that status. Otherwise, if the user goes to the application view, it should show ALL applications.

Here is the code of the View for my overview:

```
    <table class="table tablesorter" id="tblAffs">
  <thead>
  <tr class="tblhead">
    <th>AM</th>
    <th>Qualified Prospect</th>
    <th>Unqualified Prospect</th>
    <th>Contacted</th>
    <th>Converted To Account</th>
    <th>Pending Integration</th>
    <th>Revenue Generating</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  @foreach ($totalCount as $id => $name) {{-- id is the admin id --}}
    @foreach($name as $n => $status)  {{-- $n is the name, $status is array of the counts --}}
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{$n}}
        <br>
        <a href="#">Closed</a>
      </td>
          <td><a href="/ap1/{{$new_lead}}/applications?status=2">{{ isset($status[2]) ? $status[2] : 0 }}</a></td>
          <td><a href="/ap1/{{$new_lead}}/applications?status=1">{{ isset($status[1]) ? $status[1] : 0 }}</a></td>
          <td><a href="/ap1/{{$new_lead}}/applications?status=3">{{ isset($status[3]) ? $status[3] : 0 }}</a></td>
          <td><a href="/ap1/{{$new_lead}}/applications?status=4">{{ isset($status[4]) ? $status[4] : 0 }}</a></td>
          <td><a href="/ap1/{{$new_lead}}/applications?status=5">{{ isset($status[5]) ? $status[5] : 0 }}</a></td>
          <td><a href="/ap1/{{$new_lead}}/applications?status=6">{{ isset($status[6]) ? $status[6] : 0 }}</a></td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
  @endforeach



  </tbody>
</table>
```

On my controller for this overview this is the code and how data structure created:

```
     public function overview()
  {
    $query= DB::table('admins')
      ->join('advertiser_applications', 'admins.id', '=', 'advertiser_applications.assigned_to')
      ->selectRaw('advertiser_applications.status, admins.id, admins.first_name, COUNT(advertiser_applications.status) count')
      ->groupBy('admins.id', 'advertiser_applications.status');

    $counts = $query->get();
    $totalCount = [];
    foreach($counts as $count){
      $totalCount[$count->id][$count->first_name][$count->status] = $count->count;
    }
    return View::make('admin.crm.overview', ['totalCount' => $totalCount, 'admin_id' => AuthAdmin::admin(false), 'tpl_title' => 'CRM Advertiser Overview', 'new_lead' => 'advertisers']);

  }
```

Here is the code from my Controller for my view that brings up the list. This is where I am confused as to how I will pass in that status and id if that href is clicked.

```
   public function index($param)
  {
    $query = AdvertiserApplication::with('admin');
    $status = Input::get('status');

    if (!empty($status) || $status === '0')
      $query->where('status', '=', $status);

    $applications = $query->get();

    return View::make('admin.advertisers.application_list', ['applications' => $applications, 'admin_id' => AuthAdmin::admin(false)]);
  }
```

Now I am not sure if that is the proper way to link that I have written in my href. Should I do a URL link to route or something like that? I am not sure yet. Any tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

With this your URL:

```
 <a href="/ap1/{{$new_lead}}/applications?status=2">{{ isset($status[2]) ? $status[2] : 0 }}</a>
```

If you have

```
route::get('/ap1/{new_lead}', array('as' => 'page-name', 'uses' => 'yourController@functionName'));
```

in controller:

```
public function functionName($new_lead){
 // use $new_lead here to get your data
}
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but the thing is new_lead is some other variable that just tells me if advertiser or seller. What I am trying to send is $id from the $totalCount array (that you see in the first foreach statement) and that status number. status[1] or status[2] etc.

Comment: Now if you're passing ID that's cool. just replace $new_lead with $id and get $id in your controller, query the DB base on that $id and see if it's advertiser or seller. I believe $id is unique.

Comment: Its not, but that makes sense, I can just pass both status and id? or would it be ok to leave status as hard coded in the get and send only id to controller and controller accept id?

Comment: Also Michel, can you explain the route::get part. Do I put that in the href instead of the "/ap1/{{$new_lead...?

Comment: @Milan AM the value is pass in href, the route only passes the parameter to controller
 An example <a href="/page/2"> in this Route::get('/page/{id}', ....); Controller public function page($id) here $id will return 2.